# free form pro: repeatable fieldset

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I am creating a signup form for an event where you can register multiple users at once. Does free form pro support some sort of repeatable blocks?
Clicking "add another user" would add additional fields for name, surname and emailadres.

Tnx,
Kristoffer

Answer (score 1):

Currently, stock, there are no Matrix or Grid like fieldtypes. Sorry.
There is however this: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/grid-fieldtype-for-freeform